# ValueError: X has 3 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 35 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, random-forest

I'm working on a Flask Application with a pretrained RandomForestClassifier model and I came accross this error which I've so far I've understood is due to a missmatch in the number of features in my training dataset and the one I'm trying to pass from the flask form to the model. When I test the model with the X_test data created from spliting the main dataset to training and testing dataset it works just fine.
But when I try to test it with the values from the HTML form filled by the user I get this error. The same code that initiates the Keys/Features in the training and testing dataset is the same one that I've incorporated in the code below starting from the `cartegorical_features` line. I observed that the datatype returned by `X_test` is a `csr_matrix` while the one returned by the data from the form is an `ndarray` ; I put the values into a dictionary then turned that to a database using the `pd.DataFrame` but this seems to work kinda differently than I imagined.I then tried to convert the data to `csr_matrix` using `sparce.csr_matrix` I appologize if the error is obvious and any help will be highly appreciated.

Here's a sample of my code:(I created a CSV file as the dataset)

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def predict():
form =  PredictForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    gp = form.gradepoints.data
    Dfos = form.DFOS.data
    passion = form.Passion.data

    subj1 = form.sub1.data
    subj2 = form.sub2.data
    subj3 =form.sub3.data
    subj4 = form.sub4.data

    # calculating the cluster points from the subjects
    total = 0
    a = [subj1,subj2,subj3,subj4]
    for number in a:
        total +=number
    # we define a divide function to handle the division process
    def divide(a,b):
        return float(a)/b
    d = divide(total,48)
    if round(d) <= 1:
        d = 1
    # print(d)
    s = divide(gp,84)
    if round(s) <=1:
        s=1
    # print(s)
    y = int(d*s)
    p = y*48
    # print(p)
    cp = isqrt(p)
    

    # We put our values into a dataframe
    da = {'DFOS':[Dfos],'CP':[cp],'PASSION':[passion]}
    x = pd.DataFrame(data=da)
    
    print(type(x))
    print(x.shape)
  
    # we then encode it using OneHotEncoder
    cartegorical_features = ["DFOS","CP","PASSION"]
    one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
    transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot",one_hot,cartegorical_features)], remainder="passthrough")
    transformed_x = transformer.fit_transform(x)
    x = transformed_x#this is the variable holding the user's data
    
    # Converting the data from an ndarray to a csr_matrix format
    x = csr_matrix(x)
    # we then transform it to a dataset
    pd.DataFrame(x) 
    print(type(x))

    prediction = model.predict(x)

    if prediction is not None:
        return redirect (url_for('result', prediction=prediction))

    # return render_template('predict.html', title='predict', form=form, prediction=prediction)
return render_template('predict.html', title='predict', form=form)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be fitting the transformer on the input data, just using a saved transformer to transform that data. Perhaps easiest to put that transformer together with your model in a `Pipeline`.

Comment: Can you show this in code?